# Composer load single class with namespace

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I'm trying to use symfony flex with a bundle.

I have this directory structure

```
/
  src/
    AppBundle/
       AppBundle.php
       # Many classes
    Kernel.php
```

I want to load Kernel.php class with this namespace `App` and classes inside AppBundle with the namespace `AppBundle`.

I've tried many composer configurations but I couldn't load them.

```
"psr-4": {
    "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle/",
     "App\\": "src/"
}
```

But I got errors like this:

```
Expected to find class "App\AppBundle\AppBundle" in file "/var/www/vhosts/flex/src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php"
```

**UPDATE**

src/Kernel.php class have a different namespace and I couldn't change it because other classes used it, the namespace is `App`. Some scripts call that class using `use App\Kernel`

`src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php` class has this namespace `AppBundle`

There is way to do this?

**UPDATE 2**

I sorted it out:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        { "App\\Kernel": "src/Kernel.php" }
    ]
},
```

Comment: try like that `"AppBundle\\": "src/",`

Comment: I got this exception


```Attempted to load class "AppBundle" from namespace "AppBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "AppBundle\AppBundle"?```

Comment: okay, try use that class in your Kernel.php `namespace AppBundle\AppBundle`

Comment: that's where I'm trying to use it.

Comment: `"psr-4": {
     "App\\AppBundle\\": ""
}`

Comment: Update your question with the namespace line and the class line for Kernel.php and AppBundle.php.  Your composer looks right.  I suspect your namespace lines are wrong.  And be sure to run "composer dumpautoload" after updating composer.json.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @anacona16 found any answer yet ? I'm facing the same problem !

Comment: @SlimenTN yes, please see my second update.

Comment: @anacona16 I did it but still the same error!

Comment: Did you run composer dumpautoload after adding the piece of code in composer.json file?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a classmap for Kernel.php instead:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle" },
    "classmap": [ "src/Kernel.php" ]
}
```

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Comment: From the documentation it looked like it would resolve the class name by searching for classes in all .php files. In that case you might want to create a src/App/Kernel.php and then modify your psr-4 autoload accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You only need

```
"psr-4": { "App\\": "src/" }
```